# Sorting a dictionary by key and converting it into an array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of prices and quantities. I am getting updates on the price and values multiple times in a second so I don't want to store them in an array because dictionary are much faster.

```
let mainPriceValDict = [Double:Double]()
```

The data is coming in as an array of JSON so I am using codable to parse the JSON and put it into a dictionary. When I use the data, it needs to be sorted in ascending and/or descending order because I am looping through each price in order to get to a certain total quantity. The format that the array is in that I am looping through is as follows:

```
let loopingArray = [PriceQuantityEntry]()

struct PriceQuantityEntry {
    let price : Double
    let size : Double
}
```

I want to sort the prices which are the keys in the dictionary above and convert them into an array of PriceQuantityEntry. What is the best way to do this? In ascending and deciding order. I have tried first getting all the keys sorted and then grabbing associated values and putting them into the array in order but this seems like more processing than this task actually requires.

I think the best way to do this would be to put a custom initializer in the struct to convert the dictionary value to a value of type `PriceQuantityEntry` but I am not exactly sure how that would work with the sorting.

This is what I am currently doing to get it to work. I just feel like there is a more efficient way for it to be done. If you feel like I should keep the structure as an array instead of converting it to a dict, let me know.

```
loopingArray = self.mainPriceValDict.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }.map { PriceQuantityEntry(price: $0.0, size: $0.1) }
```

Comment: Don't fight the framework. If you need a specific order use an array. Sorting keys and moving values causes the loss of your *speed* benefit.

Comment: the reason I am using a dictionary is because the frequency with which I am receiving values is significantly higher than the frequency that I need to utilize the sorted array. I will receive about 20-30 updates to the mainPriceValDict every second but I will only convert those values to an array 2-3 times a second. Do you still think it makes sense to use an array?

Comment: I am receiving only updates to prices from the socket so if I use an array, I first need to find the location in that array to put the new value and then append the array with that value. what do you think makes more sense, to use an array or a dictionary?

Comment: Seems iike an x-y problem. Don't guess. Use Instruments and see what is fastest. Slotting an object into an array kept sorted, by using a binary search, can be very efficient, and there are other data structures like trees that are even faster. The use of a dictionary here, and thus the entire premise of the question, may be quite mistaken.

Comment: I am new to these data structures. which one do you recommend I learn and use? Are there any swift libraries that you recommend that I use since there is no native support for binary search in swift?

Comment: which tool in instruments should I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a lot of updates to individual entries, both a dictionary and an array may cause memory copies of the whole memory structure every time an entry is changed.

I would suggest using objects (classes) instead of structures.  This will allow you to use both an array and a dictionary to reference the object instances.  The dictionary will provide direct access for updates and the array will allow sequential processing in forward or backward order.

[EDIT] Example:

```
class PriceQuantityEntry 
{
    static var all:[PriceQuantityEntry] = []
    static var prices:[Double:PriceQuantityEntry] = [:]

    var price : Double
    var size  : Double

    init(price:Double, size:Double)
    {
       self.price = price
       self.size  = size
       PriceQuantityEntry.all.append(self)
       // PriceQuantityEntry.all.resort() // on demand or when new prices added
       PriceQuantityEntry.prices[price] = self
    }

    class func update(price:Double, with size:Double)
    {
       if let instance = PriceQuantityEntry.prices[price]
       { instance.size = size }
       else
       { 
         let _ = PriceQuantityEntry(price:price, size:size) 
         PriceQuantityEntry.resort()
       }
    }

    class func resort()
    {
       PriceQuantityEntry.all.sort{$0.price < $1.price}
    }        
}    

// if adding multiple initial entries before updates ...
let _ = PriceQuantityEntry(price:1, size:3)
let _ = PriceQuantityEntry(price:1.25, size:2)
let _ = PriceQuantityEntry(price:0.95, size:1)
PriceQuantityEntry.resort()

// for updates ...
PriceQuantityEntry.update(price:1, with: 2)

// going throug list ...
var count:Double = 0
var total:Double = 0
var quantity:Double = 5
for entry in PriceQuantityEntry.all
{
  total += min(entry.size,quantity-count) * entry.price
  count = min(quantity,count + entry.size)
  if count == quantity {break}
}
```

Comment: can you show me an example of how you would recommend I do this?